# What is the opposite of category of schemes

Tags: category-theory, schemes, affine-schemes

The category of schemes sits between $Aff=CRing^\text{op}$ and its free cocompletion $\hom(Aff^\text{op},Sets)$, as the locally representable functors. Dualizing, we have $CRing\subseteq Scm^\text{op}\subseteq \hom(CRing^\text{op},Set^\text{op}).$ So is there a description of $Scm^\text{op}$ that sits on the algebraic side of the duality between algebra and geometry?

[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158785/co-counter-variancy-of-the-yoneda-functor/158875#158875) interesting response by Zhen Lin Low about why covariant Yoneda is more natural than contravariant suggests perhaps we may not expect such a description ($Sets^\text{op}$ is not as familiar?)

Comment: Actually, $[\mathbf{CRing}^\mathrm{op}, \mathbf{Set}^\mathrm{op}] = [\mathbf{CRing}, \mathbf{Set}]^\mathrm{op}$.

Comment: @Zhen: oh, I see. The natural transformations go the other way. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: This may be a naive response but what about the finite cocompletion of commutative rings?